# Linux booting hang up after adding a printk statement in the kernel source code

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel

I have added single printk statement in the kernel source code. After compiling and building the kernel, when I boot-up the system it is hanging by printing the statement.

```
printk(KERN_INFO "I'm inside the function!\n");
```

I'm using core i3 machine in ubuntu 13.04, the version of kernel is 3.4.106 ( I've tried some other versions too but same happened ). **While doing the same changes in core 2 duo system**, it is booting normally.

Comment: what function?  And do you really get zero output after that printk?  this is not much to go on....

Comment: printk() call can sleep. If you are inside interrupt handler or while spin-lock head. Then the system is not supposed to sleep and that will explain whey the system hangs.

Comment: inside context_switch() function.
Whole screen is filled with "I'm inside the function" and system hanged up.

Comment: Try `trace_printk()`... `printk()` Can really screw up things in time critical functions like `context_switch()`

Comment: I'll try with trace_printk() and let you know the result.
btw if it is screwing up the things... then why it's working fine in core 2 duo?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. :)

Comment: Maybe your function is called before the console is fully initialized? Do you have any working `printk`'s before this call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `trace_printk()` instead of `printk()` helps staying non-messy in some time critical functions.

And your prints should be in ftrace buffers.

```
      $ cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      $ cat trace
```

Refer http://june-takeout.blogspot.dk/2010/01/debugging-kernel-using-ftrace-part-1.html and see section "Using trace_printk()"

Comment: trace_printk is working fine with above statement.Now,I am now trying to print the pids involved in context_switch. trace_printk( KERN_INFO "prev-pid=%d,next-pid=%d\n",(int)prev->pid,(int)next->pid);

Comment: My system is now booting, but my problem is not solved. I m not able to print the pids involved in context_switch. dmesg is not showing any message with above trace_printk statement .

Comment: modified the answer please see